# POSIX C Serial Port Write Cut Buffer

Tags: c, serial-port, posix, ansi-c, termios

3i've a small C program for read and write Hex Data over serial port. In reading i've not problems, bu when i try to write a Hex Data as this:

```
static const unsigned char cmdActuatorOn[] = "\x41\x54\x2B\x18\x12\x00\x12\x4B"
```

i see that the write function send over serial port only 5 bytes...so i suppose that it for any reason cut Hex Data at "0x00" character.
Below my serial port settings:

```
int init_port(char const *const device)
{
    int descriptor, result;
    struct termios settings;


    descriptor = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    result = fcntl(descriptor, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    result = tcgetattr(descriptor, &settings);

    settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    settings.c_cflag |=  CS8;

    settings.c_iflag |= IGNPAR;
    settings.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON | IXOFF | IXANY | INPCK);// raw data input mode
    settings.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);// raw data output
    settings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;// setting timeouts
    settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; // minimum number of chars to read in noncanonical (raw mode)
    settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 5; // time in deciseconds to wait for data in noncanonical mode (raw mode)

    cfsetispeed(&settings, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&settings, B9600);


    result = tcsetattr(descriptor, TCSANOW, &settings);

    return descriptor;
}
```

Function for write data is:

```
int write_port(void const *const data, size_t const size)
{
    unsigned char const *p = (unsigned char const *)data;
    unsigned char const *const q = (unsigned char const *)data + size;
    ssize_t n;

    while (p < q) {
        do {
            n = write(port_descriptor, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        } while (n == (ssize_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (n == (ssize_t)-1 && errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                /* Sleep for a millisecond, then retry. */
                usleep(1000);
                continue;
        }

        if (n == (ssize_t)-1)
                return errno;
        else
            if (n < (ssize_t)1)
                    return EIO;

        p += (size_t)n;
    }

    if (p != q)
        return EIO;

    return 0;
}
```

I call function write_data as below:

```
result = write_port(cmdActuatorOn, strlen(cmdActuatorOn));
```

This work fine for others binary data as:

```
static const unsigned char cmdGetCoordAddress[] = "\x40\x04\x2B\x02\x08\x52\x41\x9D";
static const unsigned char cmdReadCoordChannelAddress[] = "\x43\x12\x0B\x07\x08";
static const unsigned char cmdReadCoordPanId[] = "\xAF\x50\x2B\x07\x09\x52\x49\x90";
```

Write function in this case write all correct bytes on serial port. Only **cmdActuatorOn** not, so i suppose that 0x00 is the problem.

Where are my errors? I've wrong serial port configuration? I set it for use with Raw Mode...is ot correct?

Thanks a lot

Comment: and how are you writing the data to the port?

Comment: You are not writing "hex data". You are writing (from the looks of your code) *binary* data, which you *represent* as hex in a string. That is not "hex data".

Comment: ..and how does that thing know there are five chars, as hinted at by @isedev?  I hope the answer is not 'because of a null terminator' because, looking at the data....

Comment: I've update with write function code. [unwind] Yes...sorry i've forgot to specify Binary Data as Hex String..what kind of serial settings i've to do?

Comment: When you call `write_port()`, don't use `strlen()` since the data is not a string, but binary (as @MartinJames pointed out, just making it more concrete since you're still not showing that part of the code).

Comment: OP - you should look up what strlen() actually does, then look at your data.

Comment: ..especially the char at offset 5.

Comment: Instead of strlen() that i see return dimension 5 instead of 8 What should I use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `strlen()` on data which is not a standard C string.

To be more specific, your data has an embedded `'\0'`-byte, which in C means "end of string". Thus, `strlen("\x41\x54\x2B\x18\x12\x00\x12\x4B")` is `5`. It doesn't matter how many bytes follow that `\x00`, as far as `strlen()` is concerned the string ends there.

Since you're actually after the *size of the array*, it's better to use that, i.e. use `sizeof cmdGetCoordAddress` and so on. Note that this won't work if you don't have access to the actual array, i.e. if the array has decayed into a pointer it won't work and then you need to pass the size from the point where the array declaration is available.

Since your arrays are global, `sizeof` will work.

So write the call:

```
result = write_port(cmdActuatorOn, sizeof cmdActuatorOn);
```

Note that this *only* works since `cmdActuatorOn` is declared as an array, though. If you do the very similiar:

```
static const unsigned char *cmdGetCoordAddress = "\x40\x04\x2B\x02\x08\x52\x41\x9D";
```

Then the name `cmdGetCoordAddress` refers to a pointer of type `unsigned char *`, and `sizeof` will yield the size of that particular type (typically 4 or 8).

Comment: Ok i know. So you can tell me a solution?

Comment: Thanks alot. It work now. I've accepted this answer. Thanks a lot